# Question about setPriority() method in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have written a program to understand how Threads work.The program has a package and three classes.
[Package and classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sVrj.jpg)

The bodies of the classes are:

```
    public void print() {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            try {
            System.out.println("Name : "+t.getName()+" Priority : "+
            +t.getPriority()+" prints : "+i  );
            t.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(t.getName()+ " Priority : "+t.getPriority()+"  ***************");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
        }   
    }       

}
```

```
package thread;

public class ThreadMethods extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        Code p = new Code();
        p.print();
    }

}
```

```
package thread;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadMethods t1 = new ThreadMethods();
        ThreadMethods t2 = new ThreadMethods();
        ThreadMethods t3 = new ThreadMethods();
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t3.setName("t3");
        t1.setPriority(10);
        t2.setPriority(5);
        t3.setPriority(1);
        System.out.println("for Thread t1 : "+" Id = "
                +t1.getId()+" Name = "+t1.getName()+" Priority : "
                +t1.getPriority());
        System.out.println("for Thread t2 : "+" Id = "
                +t2.getId()+" Name = "+t2.getName()+" Priority : "
                +t2.getPriority());
        System.out.println("for Thread t3 : "+ "Id = "
                +t3.getId()+" Name = "+t3.getName()+" Priority : "
                +t3.getPriority());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

}
```

but it has an unexpected output:
[output_1-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BelVp.jpg)

[output_1-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmMtU.jpg)

as you observe, i have setted a priority for each thread.but they are being executed randomly indepentable from their priorities.for example,i expect after sleeping of threads,thread t1 wakeup and print the stars.but thread t3 with mimimum priority prints the stars.
why this happens?

Comment: Priority is only a "hint". ("Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed **in preference** to threads with lower priority. ")  And when a Thread does get time to run, it just runs as fast as any other thread. A thread with a lower priority is less likely to get time to run. But if you have fewer threads than available cores on your machine, they can all run at the same time and you wouldn't see any difference between threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i didn't understand what is the use of the setpriority () method,i know the definition of threads priority,my problem is why the method does not affect on running threads arrangement.